# How do I reroute traffic from port 80 on tun0 to port 80 on eth0?

Tags: debian, iptables

I have a webserver running on the same server that I use a VPN on. I'd like to be able to access the webserver when the VPN is both on or off. On FreeBSD this was pretty simple, in my opinion PF is much easier to use than IPTables.

I'm trying to reroute traffic from port 80/443 on **tun0** to port 80/44 on **eth0**. 
I've been reading the man pages for **iptables** but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The question title doesn't *quite* make sense as written. Traffic isn't routed *to* or *from* TCP ports in the first place (better think of them as labels instead), and TCP ports aren't associated with interfaces in any way. And none of that has anything to do with being able to use the webserver when the VPN is both on and off.

Routes for a packet are primarily chosen based on its destination IP address, by looking it up in the routing table. The usual problem – which FreeBSD *pf* (and from what I've heard, Windows) has additional built-in mechanisms for avoiding, but Linux sticks to the basics – is that the outbound 'reply' packets are routed completely independently from the inbound 'original' packets. So if you have two default routes (both through LAN gateway and through VPN), Linux will always prefer the same one.

What you usually need in this situation is source-dependent routing, or policy routing. The OS needs to know that outgoing 'reply' packets a) *from* a given source IP address, or b) belonging to certain established connections, must use a different route selection.

In the great tradition of "but Linux is about choice", you have to configure this manually by cobbling together various mechanisms. I'm assuming that you need IPv4 as well, and therefore can't rely entirely on the "subtree" mechanism (which is *much* easier to use, but unfortunately IPv6-only as implemented).

First make sure you have two routing tables, each with a different default route:

```
ip -4 route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table 2
ip -4 route add default dev tun0 table 3
```

*(Shortcut: Assuming the 'main' table already has a default route via the VPN, you don't need table 3 here, you can just use 'main' for that instead of creating table 3.)*

Then add policy-routing rules to look in that table depending on the source IP address:

```
ip -4 rule add pref 200 from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup 2
ip -4 rule add pref 300 from <vpnnet> lookup 3
```

*(Again, if the 'main' table already prefers a default route via the VPN, you can skip the latter rule. It is included here for completeness.)*

Then check the result by using:

```
ip -4 route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.x
ip -4 route get 8.8.8.8 from <vpnip>
```